# Javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have code like

```
<a id='lnk1' onclick='do something' >test</a>
```

Later on code is added to the same anchor tag like

```
lnk = document.getElementById('lnk1')
lnk.onclick = function() { do something}
```

Now what is happening is that in the second piece of code the onclick function of the anchor tag is getting overwritten. What I want to happen instead is that the first onclick's code is run and after that the 2nd onclick's is run.

Comment: Look at [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener).

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but related enough to be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790583/javascript-append-to-onclick-event

Comment: @Baszz no, that won't work. The browser will turn the string value of the attribute into a full-blown JavaScript function, so appending additional code in string form just makes no sense.

Comment: @Pointy: Okay, thanks...it was just a thought...wasn't sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very simple, standards-compliant way to do this:

```
lnk1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // do something
});
```

This doesn't work in IE before version 9, so you'll need to do this:

```
var handler = function() {
    // do something
};

if ("addEventListener" in lnk1) { // standards-compliant browsers
    lnk1.addEventListener('click', handler);
} else { // Internet Explorer < v9
    lnk1.attachEvent('onclick', handler);
}
```

This will work, and both the original function specificed in the HTML attribute and in the code above will run. **HOWEVER** it would be far nicer to define all your event handlers in the same place: in the Javascript. Think hard about removing event handling logic from your HTML attributes.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk1'); // don't forget var!

var oldHandler = lnk.onclick;
lnk.onclick = function(ev) {
  if (oldHandler) oldHandler(ev);
  // do something ...
};
```

That code saves a reference to the old handler, and if it's not empty it calls it before doing whatever else the new handler wants to do.

You could put the call to the old handler *after* the new code, or mixed in, or whatever.

Comment: @S.Serpooshan yes, if `this` is important then you'd want to use `.call()` to make sure it's correct. Also not that this answer is over 10 years old.

Comment: but this way has a potential problem: if the `this` keyword is used in oldHandler, it will be wrong! one solution is to write: `if (oldHandler) oldHandler.call(this, ev);`

Comment: @S.Serpooshan yes, re-read my comment above.

Comment: oh, i just edit my first comment before see your answer comment...

Answer (score 1):

```
<a id='lnk1' onclick='do something' >test</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 lnk1 = document.getElementById('lnk1')
    lnk1.addEventListener('click',function() { do something}, false);
```

when setting onclick you are overwrite existing attribute, but assign click through event listener then it will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your statement:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
lnk = document.getElementById('lnk1')
lnk1.onclick = function() { do something} \\ replace lnk1 with lnk
lnk.onclick = function() { do something} \\ this will work
```

You have defined `lnk` as variable but your are calling `lnk1` with `onclick` event. This is a wrong statement.

**USE HTML**

```
<a id='lnk1'>test</a>
```

See the Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tm5cX/