# calling an onchange function from external javascript

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a select dropdown in a html file that i can't really touch

```
<select id="color" onChange="javascript:changeColor(this)">
<option value="black">Black</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
<option value="gold">Gold</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to manipulate that using prototype js

```
var update_dropdown=$$('select#color option');
var option_length= update_dropdown.length;
for (var m = 0; m &lt; option_length; m++) {
    if(update_dropdown[m].value==selected_ColorId) {
        update_dropdown[m].selected=true;
    }
}
```

is there any way that i can call onChange event that is being called in the html , like in this instance changeColor()?I am using prototype js
thanks

Comment: Not exactly the same problem but this SO question my give you some insight. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790583/javascript-append-to-onclick-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call the change event itself.  Since the change event is just hooked up to a javascript function of yours, you can just call the `changeColor` function directly with the appropriate parameters to mimic when the actual event occurs.

```
var selectObj = document.getElementById('color');
changeColor.call(selectObj, selectObj);
```

This will do that same thing as `changeColor(this)`.

FYI, in the two arguments to changeColor.call(a, b), the `a` argument sets the `this` pointer in the changeColor function to be your select object and the `b` argument sets the first function argument in the changeColor function to be your select object to match how you have it called in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [event.simulate.js](https://github.com/kangax/protolicious/blob/5b56fdafcd7d7662c9d648534225039b2e78e371/event.simulate.js) to trigger the change event on the `<select>`. jQuery is also capable of triggering native events programatically.